# Hard to start in the summer

Tags: engine, starting, dodge, ram

Dodge Ram 2500
1st start of day, turns over and starts. 
After extended drive time it becomes harder to start and as day becomes warmer/hotter. 
Temps are hitting the 90's and 100+ Fahrenheit. 
Heat issues? Starter issues?
I'm unsure and don't want to pay for 'could be'.

Comment: Because you mention "starter", is the problem that you are seeing that the engine won't turn over? Or is it cranking and cranking and won't catch/start? What kind of engine does the 2500 have (gas/diesel)?